# how to get only date from dataframe column with date time value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

My dataframe contents are like:

```
df['Date']
2016/12/31 PM 04:50:00
2016/12/30 AM 02:20:00
2016/12/2 PM 01:51:00
2016/12/10 PM 03:33:00
```

How to get only date value? original dtype is object, I want 2016/12/31 PM 04:50:00 → 2016/12/31

Comment: Do you want date values or date strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

Minimal example

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2017', periods=72, freq='H')

>>> rng[0]
Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00', offset='H')

>>> rng[0].strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
'2017/01/01
```

NB: Depending on the exact datatypes, you may need to explicitly cast.

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df['rng'] = rng
>>> pd.DatetimeIndex(df['rng']).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
array(['2017/01/01', '2017/01/01', '2017/01/01', '2017/01/01',
...
```

Comment: hi, I have df['Date'] data, I can't use your example, if I use df['Date'].strftime('%Y/%m/%d'), it showed me AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: That's what the NB on cast is for. `pd.DatetimeIndex` has the `strftime()` attribute, not `pd.Series`.

Comment: I think I don't know how to change my df['Date'] to pd.date_range('1/1/2017', periods=72, freq='H'), and as I use pd.DatetimeIndex, it show me "Unknown string format"

Comment: As a first pass, `pd.DatetimeIndex( df['Date'] )` will accomplish the change. `pd.date_range()` was just used to generate sample data for the minimal example.

Comment: I think I found the reason, maybe the AM/PM data are traditional chinese word "早上/下午", I can't specify format. So I use lambda to fix my problem.
Thank you for your reply.